# Ignore settings.json file when using nexe or pkg

Tags: node.js

I created a Discord bot i want to share with others but the community i want to share it with got a bad habbit of removing credits and so on.

What i am trying to do is compile my bot script in to native code i have tryed nexe, and that works fine, but i dont want it to encode the settings file, where the users need to add there bot token, and channels that the bot should work with.

I Tryed looking in to PKG to but i can't find a clear answer on how to do this, is there anyone out there that can lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ways around this:

1. Have the user pass in the settings file location as the first argument to the binary: `./binary ./settings.json`
2. Have the user set an environment variable with the settings file location: `BINARY_SETTINGS=/home/user/settings.json ./binary`
3. Expect the settings file location to be the current directory of the binary

For example, to do 3 with `pkg`, you can use the suggestion in [the docs](https://github.com/zeit/pkg/blob/master/README.md):

> On the other hand, in order to access real file system at run time (pick up a user's external javascript plugin, json configuration or even get a list of user's directory) you should take `process.cwd()` or `path.dirname(process.execPath)`.

Comment: Okay so i should open the file via path.dirname(process.execPath) or what ?

Comment: Tryed using const settings = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'settings.js'))

But that ehm closes the crashes it instantly sadly i dont get a error code.

Comment: Did `settings.js` exist in the directory where you ran the binary?

Comment: Figured it out had to do it in a bit of an odd way to get it working but it's working now.

const thisPath = process.cwd()
const certPath = path.join(thisPath, 'test.js');
const cert = fs.readFileSync(certPath, "utf8");

Comment: Weird. I was able to get it working with: ```const settings = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'settings.js'), 'utf8')```. Does this solve your original question then?

Comment: I was having that same problem with `pkg` and `nexe` for packaging (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe) and the `process.cwd()` trick worked for both. For example: `const conf = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'config.json'), 'utf8');`